# R: how does the which() function operate

Tags: r

I am confused about the which function. Basically I thought that it checks at which position of an input object (e.g., a vector) a logical condition is true. As seen in the documentation:

```
which(LETTERS == "R")
[1] 18
```

In other words, it goes through all LETTERS values and checks if value == R. But this seems to be a misunderstanding. If I input

```
a <- c("test","test2","test3","test4")
b <- c("test","test3")
which(a==b)
[1] 1
```

it returns `[1] 1` although test3 does also appear in both vectors. Also, if I input a shorter vector for a, it returns a warning:

```
a <- c("test","test2","test3")
b <- c("test","test3")
which(a==b)
[1] 1

Warning message:
In a == b : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

My question here is twofold:

1. How can I return the positions of a character vector a that match a character vector b?
2. How does which() operate because I obviously misunderstand the function.

Thank you for your answers

Edit: thank you for your quick replies, you clarified my misunderstanding!

Comment: `match(a, b)`...

Comment: Thank you! The documentation says "match: An integer vector giving the position in table of the first match if there is a match, otherwise nomatch." If a appears multiple times in b, does it return every index/position or only the first?

Comment: by the way - `match(a,b)` is the same as `a %in% b` see `??base::match`

Comment: `x %in% y` is the same as `match(x, y, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `which` an input that tells it what elements of a are in b:

```
which(a%in%b)
[1] 1 3
```

`which` essentially identifies which elements are `TRUE` in a logical vector.

Answer (score 3):

`==` compares values 1 by 1  `(a[1]==b[1]);(a[2]==b[2]).....` and not as sets.

for set operations use `%in%`

use `a[which(a %in% b)]`  to get `[1] "test"  "test3"`

**which()** returns the index of TRUE expressions (!) not the value.

`which(a %in% b)` will return

```
[1] 1    3
```

the reason for the strange warning message is R's recycling

```
Warning message:
In a == b : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

so when you compare a vector of length 4 with a vector of length 2, value by value (using `==` ), R 'recycles' the short vector. in 4 and 2 it works and you will get an answer for this question: (a1==b1,a2==b2,a3==b1,a4==b2). in case of length 4 and 3 - you get a warning message saying the short vector cannot be multiplied by an integer to get the long vector length.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!